# Moving a list of items vertically

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a map and a list of items underneath. 
I want to move the list up (while maintaining the position of the map) until the user reaches the last element of the list. In that case, the list shouldn't move up anymore.

The problem is that the list continues to move upwards even after the last element has been shown living a white background.

template:

```
<GridLayout rows="*, *, 0" columns="*"> 
<MapView row="0" col="0"> ...
<GridLayout #list rows="*, 0" columns="*" #list row="1" col="0">
    <GridLayout row="0" col="0" class="m-15"
        rows="..." (pan)="onPan($event)">
        ...
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
<GridLayout #ref row="2" col="0">...
```

component.ts

```
onPan(args: PanGestureEventData) {
    switch (args.state) {
      case 1:
        break;
      case 2:
        const diff = this.ref.nativeElement.getLocationRelativeTo(this.list.nativeElement);
        if (diff > 1400) return; // I used 1400 seems based on various devices sizes, it seems like a good number. 
        this.dragContainer.translateY += args.deltaY - this.prevDeltaY;
        this.prevDeltaY = args.deltaY;

        break;
      case 3:
      default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**Expected: **
- I expect that when the last element in the list has been shown, the list is not able to move up anymore

**Actual: **
- The list continues to move upward leaving a white background.

I have created a demo on nativescript playground here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=rB4H2M

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266962/how-to-translate-y-a-gridlayout-upwards-in-nativescript-angular ?

Comment: I don't see exactly where you are checking for the visibility of last item. Can you share a complete Playground sample?

Comment: @Narendra yep sorry, Ill delete it.

Comment: @Manoj I have updated the code to reflex my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to find an example which basically does what I needed. The effect I was trying to achieve is called Parallax and here is an example of Nativescript Demo Samples

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=b9hyJh&v=2